# How do I access sails.services.*?

Tags: node.js, web-applications, sails.js

I am using sails.js in a node app. Sails of course is globally available by default. However, I want my services and models to be non-global for peace of mind. I set those default booleans in globals.js to false and am trying to access specific services as per the sails.js documentation (sails.services.*) this should work since sails is still global, however it keeps throwing a reference error. Any ideas why this is? Does anyone have experience mucking around with global.js in sails and can confirm of the documentation of sails.js is innacurate? Starting to lean towards that conclusion.
Note: using sails.js version 11

Answer (score 1):

if you accesss service trough `sails.services.xxx` make sure that all letters are lower case, example if you have `MyService.js` at services folder, so you can call it by `MyService` or `sails.service.myservice`.